# kernel_task no real memory

Tags: macos

Is there way to set memory for `kernel_task`? `kernel_task` does not use real memory:

[image: No Memory]

Comment: kernel_task isn't really a real process. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you think that kernel_task needs more memory?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to set away memory for "kernel_task". The macOS operating system kernel automatically manages memory, so there is no need for users to assign memory in this way.